# Jquery countdown plugin, date from Mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to modifie the JS script so I can get the date from a database instead of typing it manually. I don't really know how to get right format on the date. The plugin only use  days, hours, minutes, seconds.

Is there someone that can help me?

Jquery countdown [plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

Original:

```
$(function () {
var austDay = new Date();
austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 2);
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
$('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});

</script>
```

Modified:

```
<?php $waa = '1441894898' ?>

<script>

$(function () {
var austDay = <?php echo json_encode($waa); ?>;
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin don't only use years, months, etc..., but a javascript `Date` ([reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)) instance. So if your `$waa` variable is the date from what you want to count down, and it is in milliseconds, the `var austDay = new Date(<?php echo $waa; ?>);` code should work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried that code but only gets 0 days, 0hours etc...@nvi9

Comment: The problem should with the value of `$waa` (1441894898). It represents a date near 1970 (in milliseconds), so the days, hours, etc to that date expectedly 0... Try with 1454281200000 or something greater.
What type of database do you use? (How it stores the date?)

Comment: I added tree 0 and it work. (Multicera with 1000). Please upvote the question if it was a good one. @nvi9

Answer (score 0):

That is mostly easily done with strtotime as it will pretty much recognize any time format you want. Then you can output it anyway you want. I use the following

```
date(MM/DD/YY, strtotime($waa))
```

For you it would most likely look like this

```
<?php echo json_encode(date(MM/DD/YY, strtotime($waa))); ?>
```

Not sure what format you need the date in but you can use the manual for date to get the format of the date you need right. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)